# saving solution file in Visual web Developer to my preferred location

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am using Visual web developer Express and Today I started my first tutorial.
When I create a new Website even though I select the path to save my website, the solution file will always be saved in  "Visual studio2010/projects" 
In C# or C, the solution file will be saved to the path that I chose?
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

2 Options.

1) File -> Save "[Solution Name].sln" As...

2) Create the Solution File on it's own, saving it to the file path of your choosing, and then add the projects to the Solution.

Hope this helps